# Can I use Pearson correlation to find out if there's correlation between two dataset, which is ordered by date

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, analytics, data-science

I have 3 columns of data. columnA is number of users in percentage. columnB is cost spent on campaign as a percentage of total cost. I would like to find out if there's any correlation between the cost spent on campaign and the number of users. But the data is a time series data like the following:(date range is 2 years daily data)

```
  Date        No.of users%  Cost spent%
2010-01-01    50%             40%
2010-01-02    55%             41%
2010-01-03    54%             42%
....
```

I don't think we could directly use Pearson Correlation coef to calculate the correlation since they are time series. However, I was wondering, if I aggregate these data to "Day of Month" like the following:

```
Day of Month  No.of users%  Cost spent%
1               50%             40%
2               55%             41%
3               54%             42%
....
30              51%             48%
31              52%             47%
```

If I group the data into this format, Can I use Pearson correlation coef to find out the correlation?

I found some posts here suggest to use cross-correlation but I'm thinking if there's an alternative. 
Thank you so much

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question here. You have two variables (cost and users) sampled from a source daily for two years. Why can you not compare them directly with Pearson if your question is simply about their correlation? I am not sure in what way time is important to your question about their correlation.

Comment: A Pearson correlation  would NOT take into account the time ordering of the data. This is, of course, the wrong venue to display your desire for statistical education. You might have posed a question that could be adequately demonstrated with R code but you chose to offer only a fragment of the data and therefore prevented a data-driven answer. Almost all questions that use some number of adjacent dots (".....") are similarly flawed. They suggest that we can see your data. We CANNOT. It's your responsibility to present a [MCVE]

Comment: @17thLvlBotanist: You might want to extend your knowledge of statistical methods. Time series data have rich sets of additional issues (see the `?acf` help page to get a staring point)  that go well beyond those you encounter in a basic stats class. Analyzing the data with Pearson coefficient would throw away most of the interesting information about the  joint odering.

Comment: @42 I understand that. What I did not understand from the phrasing of the question was whether the asker really cared about the time dimension or if she only cared about the correlation of the variables but wondered how time might throw a wrench into the works of that. I apologize if my prior comment/question about that was confusing.